# Search with Turkish characters

Tags: postgresql, search, elasticsearch, pattern-matching, sql-like

I have problem on db search with like and elastic search in Turkish upper and lower case.

For example I have posts table which contains post titled `'DENEME YAZI'`.

If I run this query:

```
select * from posts where title like '%deneme%';
```

or:

```
select * from posts where title like '%YAZI%';
```

I get correct result but if I run:

```
select * from posts where title like '%yazı%';
```

it doesn't return any record. My database encoding is `tr_TR.UTF-8`.
How can I get correct results without entering exact word?

Answer (score 3):

You must use `ILIKE` for case insensitive matches:

```
select * from posts where title ilike '%yazı%';
```

**However**, there is the additional complication of peculiar rules in the Turkish locale. Upper case of **`'ı'`** is **`'I'`**. But not the other way round. Lower case of **`'I'`** is **`'i'`**:

```
db=# SELECT lower(upper('ı'));
 lower
-------
 i
```

You *could* solve that by applying `upper()` on either side of the `LIKE` expression:

```
select upper('DENEME YAZI') like ('%' || upper('yazı') || '%');
```

Comment: You have made my day !

Answer (score 1):

Applying just a single UPPER (or LOWER) on either side of the expression is not a solution. You should handle problematic Turkish characters (ıI-iİ) by yourself.

- İ and i are the same letters in Turkish alphabet.
- I and ı are the same letters in Turkish alphabet.

But even using UTF-8, Latin5, Windows 1254 Encoding and collation settings in postgre

- UPPER('İ') returns 'İ'  OK
- UPPER('i') return  'I'  Not OK
- UPPER('I') returns 'I'  OK
- UPPER('ı') return  'İ'  Not OK

so

- SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ... UPPER('İZMİR') like UPPER('izmir') return false
- SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ... UPPER('ISPARTA') like UPPER('ısparta') return false.

Here's some **more precise** but **not perfect** solution because of performance issues

```
SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ... 
UPPER(REPLACE(REPLACE(COLUMNX, 'i', 'İ'), 'ı', 'I')) = UPPER(REPLACE(REPLACE(myvalue, 
'i', 'İ'), 'ı', 'I'))
```

or

```
SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ... 
UPPER(TRANSLATE('COLUMNX','ıi','Iİ')) = UPPER(TRANSLATE(myvalue,'ıi','Iİ'))
```