# (SQL ilike) Could not get desired result while search with turkish character 'ı' and 'I'

Tags: postgresql

I have a SQL query that is given below

```
select * from drivers d
where d.surname ilike concat('%', '$2::text, '%')
```

Problem is in turkish we have conflicting letters for letter 'i'. lowercase 'I' is 'ı' and we have 'İ' as uppercase 'i'. When i try to search a word containing lowercase 'ı' i couldn't get words that contain uppercase 'I' and vice versa. For example if i want to search 'akın' i couldn't get results containing 'AKIN' or if i search for 'AKIN' i couldn't get results containing 'akın'. How can i get this to work? Is there a way to give culture or something?

I tried using regex but i couldn't find a solution.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Search with Turkish characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24295566/search-with-turkish-characters)

Comment: The duplicate shows how to handle this *but*, performance will be bad - it's already bad, because `LIKE '%blah%'` can't use any indexes and has to scan the entire table. If you want to search for phrases or words you should consider using [full text search operators and indexes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/textsearch-intro.html). If you use `LIKE '%%` to autocomplete surnames you should consider using only a prefix search (ie `like 'blah%`). Such a search can be accelerated by normal indexes

Answer (score 1):

You have to make sure you are using a Turkish collation:

```
SELECT 'akın' ILIKE '%AKIN%' COLLATE "tr_TR.utf8";

 ?column? 
══════════
 t
(1 row)
```

To speed up a query like this, you need a trigram index:

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS pg_trgm;

CREATE INDEX ON drivers USING gin (surname gin_trgm_ops);
```